# How to select bytes from byte array between two byte arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, byte

How can I select/cut byte array, `allBytes` are representation for bytes from file returned by `Files.readAllBytes( file.toPath() )`.

```
    byte[] allBytes = new byte[] {50, 60, 70, 10, 20, 30, 40, -50, -40, 10}; 
    byte[] cutStart = new byte[]{60, 70}
    byte[] cutEnd = new byte[]{-50}
    // do something that will return
    byte[] finalBytes = {60, 70, 10, 20, 30, 40, -50};
```

So basically I will provide two byte arrays to the method, `cutStart` and `cutEnd`, and it should return everything between all matches. So there should be more than one match in `allBytes`so it should return a byte matrix.

**Approach detail**

If you open any binary file in Hex Editor, you can see something like this:
[image]
There is bunch of characters on right side as you can see. Some files ( not this one ) contain paths to windows dll libraries I wish to list:

```
byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes( new File("path-to-file").toPath() );
byte[] start = "C:/Windows/".getBytes(); //System.getEnv() later...
byte[] end = ".dll".getBytes();
```

So the final output should list all path links found inside binary file:

```
"C:/windows/.....dxd9.dll"
"C:/windows/.....msvcp120.dll"
```

**EDIT:** 
According to answer's idea:

```
byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes( file.toPath() );
   String bytesString = new String(fileBytes);

  int startIndex = bytesString.indexOf("C:/windows/");
  int endIndex = bytesString.lastIndexOf(".dll");

  byte[] cut = Arrays.copyOfRange( fileBytes, startIndex, endIndex );
  String c = new String(cut);
```

Which returns very long string where it starts with first matched path and ends with last one.

```
String str = "Xabcd...Y...1234.....XefghY";
```

Where `X` is start of path I want and `Y` end. How can I get String array from `String str`

```
 String[] results = new String[] { "Xabcd...Y", "XefghY" }
```

Comment: This sounds like a problem from a text book (please correct me if I'm wrong). Did you try taking a stab at it? Please share any code resulting from your attempt.

Comment: I looking for something like `Arrays.copyOfRange()` but I'll provide byte array instead of index.

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to iterate.

Comment: updated my question.